# Can we make the public site URL enable or disable based on Case status values?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites

I created public site with Case information, i am going to send this site link as a email to user when the Case status field changed to Forward buyer using work flow. Can we make the link only available when the status is Forward buyer the link won't be available if the status is closed. Can we achieve this via Apex?Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Lavanya.

Apex Code:

```
public class Case_Update
{


       public List<Case> case_update;

    public Id caseId {get;set;}
    public Case cases {get;set;}
    public Case case_record{get; set;}
    public String recordID {get; set;}
     public PageReference pr{get;set;}

     public string reason{get;set;}
     public String resolution{get;set;}
     public String resolution_comments{get;set;}

   /* public Case_Update(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {

    }*/
    public Case_Update(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
    cases =new Case();
    recordID = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
    case_record= [SELECT Id,Full_Name__c, Resolution__c,Email_Address__c, Reason__c, Response_Status__c,Resolution_Comments__c,RecordType.Name FROM Case WHERE id=:recordID AND RecordType.Name= 'Big W No Show Case' LIMIT 1];

    system.debug('****'+recordID);
    //fetchAccountDetails();
    }
     public pageReference updates(){

        case_record.Reason__c=reason;
        case_record.Resolution_Comments__c=resolution_comments;
        case_record.Resolution__c=resolution;

        update case_record;

        PageReference pr = new PageReference('http://devperi-woolworths.cs18.force.com/?id='+recordId);
        ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Updated successfully')); 
       // apexpages.addmessage(msg);
       // pr.setRedirect(true);
         pr = null;
        return pr;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getReasons()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        options.add(new SelectOption('Late Delivery','Late Delivery'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Early Delivery','Early Delivery'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('PO not booked','PO not booked'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Unsafe load','Unsafe load'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Driver failed to complete site induction','Driver failed to complete site induction'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Pallets stacked incorrectly','Pallets stacked incorrectly'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Invalid PO number','Invalid PO number'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('PO supplied to wrong DC','PO supplied to wrong DC'));

        return options;
    } 
     public List<SelectOption> getResolutions()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        options.add(new SelectOption('Order Cancelled','Order Cancelled'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Order Delivered / PO Received in SFR','Order Delivered / PO Received in SFR'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Proof of Delivery Requested / DC Query to be raised','Proof of Delivery Requested / DC Query to be raised'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Re-booking Request Raised','Re-booking Request Raised'));

        return options;
    } 

    /*public void fetchAccountDetails()
    { 
      cases =[select Full_Name__c,Email_Address__c,Priority ,Origin,Status,Subject,Number_Pallets_Cartons__c,Description,Event_Number__c,XD_FD__c,Type,Reason__c,PO__c,ContactId,Distribution_Centre__c,Vendor_Number__c,Resolution__c,Response_Status__c,Resolution_Comments__c from Case Limit 1]; 

     }  
    public List<Case> getCases()
    {
          case_update =[select Full_Name__c,Email_Address__c,Priority ,Origin,Status,Subject,Number_Pallets_Cartons__c,Description,Event_Number__c,XD_FD__c,Type,Reason__c,PO__c,ContactId,Distribution_Centre__c,Vendor_Number__c,Resolution__c,Response_Status__c,Resolution_Comments__c from Case Limit 1]; 

           return case_update ; 
    }*/

    }
```

Vf Code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="Case_Update" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<div id="pagewrap1">
<p id="element"><apex:image url="http://www.bigw.com.au/media/images/Eagerlama/head-bg.png"/></p>
<p id="element1">BigW Case Management</p>
</div>

<div class="header">
<p id="element2">No Show Update Form</p>

</div>
<div class="content">

<apex:form >
<apex:pageMessages escape="false"></apex:pageMessages>
<!--<apex:messages />-->
 <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Case Information">
   <apex:outputField value="{!case.CaseNumber}" />
       <apex:outputField value="{!case.Status}" />

  <apex:outputField value="{!case.Full_Name__c}" />
  <apex:outputField value="{!case.Email_Address__c}" />

  <apex:outputField value="{!case.Reason__c}" />
  <apex:outputField value="{!case.Number_Pallets_Cartons__c}" />
  <apex:outputField value="{!case.Description}" />

  <apex:outputField value="{!case.Type}" />

   </apex:pageBlockSection>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="PO Information" >

  <apex:outputField value="{!case.PO__c}" />
  <apex:outputField value="{!case.ContactId}" />
  <apex:outputField value="{!case.Distribution_Centre__c}" />
  <apex:outputField value="{!case.Vendor_Number__c}" />
  <apex:outputField value="{!case.XD_FD__c}" />
    <apex:outputField value="{!case.Event_Number__c}" />


   </apex:pageBlockSection>
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Other Information" columns="2"> 

<apex:pageblockSectionItem >
<apex:outputLabel value="Resolution"/>               
<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!resolution}" style="width: 180px; height: 20px" >
 <apex:selectOptions value="{!resolutions}" />
</apex:selectList>
 </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

 <!--<apex:pageblockSectionItem >
 <apex:outputLabel value="Reason"/>
 <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!reason}">
 <apex:selectOptions value="{!reasons}"/>
</apex:selectList>
 </apex:pageblockSectionItem> -->  
   <apex:inputtext value="{!resolution_comments}" label="Resolution Comments" style="width: 130px; height: 35px"/>

 </apex:pageBlockSection>

 <!--<apex:repeat value="{!case_record}" var="c">
                               <apex:inputField value="{!c.Resolution__c}"/>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!c.Response_Status__c}"/>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!c.Resolution_Comments__c}"/>


</apex:repeat>-->

             <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">

 <apex:commandButton value="Update" action="{!updates}"/>
  <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>

             </apex:pageBlockButtons>

 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware no. But you can always ***render/redirect*** the page based on your criteria.

IE:

> **If:**
>   criteria is not met display a nice message saying "the information is not yet available".
>
> **Else:**
>   display case information. This can be achieve using any of the rendered attributes which Salesforce allows on certain tags such as pageBlock, pageBlockSection or just redirect them to another page which is your generic "this information is not available yet".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this way and update you.

Comment: Yeah, either display content or use pageReference to push them to a default "no access" page.